# Como exibir o total de registros em um relacionamento ManyToMany quando uso HAVING?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho as tabelas abaixo:

- articles
- tags
- article_tag (pivot table com as colunas article_id e tag_id)

Na consulta abaixo eu consigo recuperar os artigos que possuem as duas tags (com id 1 e 3). Na query somente artigos que tenham as duas tags que terão seus ids mostrados.

```
select article_id
from article_tag
where tag_id in (1, 3)
group by article_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2;
```

Como fazer um select count para eu saber o total de registros retornados sem exibir os dados em si?

É que na query acima eu tenho a listagem por exemplo:

```
| article_id |
--------------
| 289        |
| 341        |
```

Mas eu queria algo como (total de artigos que tem as duas tags):

```
| total_articles |
------------------
| 2              |
```

Comment: article_id é PK?

Comment: Sim, PK na tabela articles e FK na tabela article_tag

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que seria isto que você quer, deve selecionar o COUNT do campo article_id para que retorne a quantidade de registros.

```
select COUNT(article_id)
from article_tag
where tag_id in (1, 3)
group by article_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Isso sempre retorna como resultado o valor 2 que é o número de tags buscadas e também retornar mais de um registro sempre com o valor 2 (número de tag_id buscadas)

Comment: e não seria isto que voce quer? trazer a quantidade de registros que encontrou no select?

Comment: Sim, mas essa query não retorna. Ela retorna vários registros com o valor 2 que é a quantidade de tags buscadas e não a quantidade de artigos encontrados.

Comment: tente agrupar pela tag_id entao, pois desta forma acima ele agrupa pelo article_id se tiver 2 trara 2 resultados

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(article_id)
from article_tag
where tag_id in (1, 3)
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2;
```

Coloque um `COUNT` no select e retire o `groupby`